# Is there any MATLAB filter or method to fix distortion in the color gradation of images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am working on an algorithm to reduce the size of images, but there is a problem, which is that the resulting image contains distortions in color gradations, as you can see below. Is there a filter or method to treat these cravings? Thank you

I tried some of the built-in smoothing filters in MATLAB like GaussianFilter but they did not give me the desired result

Comment: image link https://imgur.com/a/Q2Ke5ri

Comment: reducing the bit depth hasn't been a sensible way to reduce file size for *decades*. compression only suffers when you do that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz know but I hope i can find a Good filter that can help